# Get items in folder using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I need to get all the items in a specific folder in a list.
I have tried few api like but it does not give me items in list. I need to get items so that I can get total length of folder.

`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Location_Ref/FolderLocation')/`

What is missing in this api?

Answer (score 0):

try this one `https://server/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<folder url>)?$expand=Files`

Comment: Please explain along

Answer (score 0):

try this
It will give all the folders and Files

```
  var folderUrl = '/documents/2015';
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Folders,Files";
```

It will give all the files

```
var folderUrl = '/documents/2015';
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Files";
```

Check this Link:

[Get all Files and Folders in one call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call)

Comment: I have tried this already, but when i do `data.d.results.length`, this does not give me the total number of items in that folder

Answer (score 0):

```
http://SITE/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Location_Ref/FolderLocation')/Files
```