# How to get documents from folder in document library sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there a **REST** way to get all the documents with its properties under a specific folder into a document library ?

I'm doing it like so:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileRef,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl,Title,URL,File&$expand=File";
```

But it gives me all documents in the lib, I tried filtering fileRef but it doesn´t worked.

So I look for a better way to accomplish that.

Thanks

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call

Answer (score 0):

You can use following REST query to retrieve the files in a folder.

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<<folder path>>')/Files"
```

Here `folder path` is your folder relative path.

Example

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/subsite/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/subsite/Documents')/Files
```

To include subfolders and files use the following syntax

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<<folder path>>')?$expand=Folders,Files"
```